# Limit number of posts in custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I want to limit the number of posts that can be created in my custom posts type to 10. Have tried with different solutions and the code below but nothing works.

```
function post_limit() {

    $post_query = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'answer' ));
    if ($post_query->have_posts()) { 

    $count_posts = wp_count_posts('answer')->publish;

    if ( $count_posts > 10 ) { 
    return false;
    }
    }
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_limit' );
```

Comment: try passing `post_count` as argument to query and you are not resetting your query by using `wp_reset_query();` after the loop, I have not tested `post_count` try it and let me know.

Comment: what do you exactly get with the code you have mentioned?